# Для чего нужны классы в Python?

Tags: python

что делает переменная self, что такое объект-экземпляр класса ?

Comment: Для того же, для чего и в других языках, self - это не оператор, что такое объект-экземпляр можно прочитать в любом учебнике.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `self` — это стандартное имя первого аргумента для методов объекта.
2. Класс — тип, описывающий устройство объектов. Объект — это экземпляр класса. Класс можно сравнить с чертежом, по которому создаются объекты. [Оригинал](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/obektno-orientirovannoe-programmirovanie-obshhee-predstavlenie.html)