# Есть ли смысл идти в хороший вуз с it направлением или лучше оставаться в домашней обстановке и заниматься самообучением?

Tags: c

Стоит выбор или учиться в другом городе в хорошем по рейтингу университете, или же ходить в местный вуз получать стипендию по 6к и совмещать как то пытаться с самообразованием. Хватает баллов от егэ в екб и питер средненький университет, на факультет программная инженерия или там прикладная математика и информатика. Помогите пожалуйста определиться кто уже прошел этот этап и может помочь нубику..

Comment: Скорее всего, ответы на этот вопрос будут основаны на мнениях, а не на фактах и цитатах. Необходимо переформулировать его так, чтобы на него можно было дать объективный ответ.

Comment: Ищите "волшебную таблетку"? Её не существует.

Comment: Идите в хороший вуз в крупном городе, но не столько за знаниями, сколько за корочкой и возможностью закрепиться в городе с бОльшими зарплатами. Заодно попривыкнете жить без родителей. В вузе могут рассказать что-то полезное, но скорее всего этого полезного будет немного - рассчитывать на вуз нельзя, нужно учиться самостоятельно, и чем раньше, тем лучше.

Comment: Кажется, что 4 года бакалавриата - это много, но если вы пойдете изучать какой-нибудь С++ (очевидный выбор, если вам понравился С, который у вас в тегах), то на его самостоятельное освоение до *нормального* уровня примерно столько времени и нужно, если не слишком торопиться.

Comment: **Плюсующие**, пожалуйста, объясните, зачем вы ставите плюсы таким вопросам?

Comment: @dIm0n  Возможно, кто-то видит вопрос  - просто понятный или к сердцу близкий - плюсует. Иначе как объяснить, что [за этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1162921/Для-чего-нужны-классы-в-python)  поставили четыре плюса (+4-9, если Вы не видите раскладку по голосам)

Comment: @dIm0n, если вопрос не по теме, это не значит, что он плохой. Ну, например, это вопрос я считаю полезным, поэтому поставил плюс.

Comment: Осваивать С придется самообучением в любом случае.

Comment: @eanmos как это? Очевидно, вопрос никак не связан с ruSO, как он может быть хорошим для ruSO? Если вы имеете в виду хороший в целом как вопрос, то здесь оценивают не это. Здесь оценивают именно хорошесть для ресурса. Иначе бы и "в чём смысл жизни?", "яйцо или курица?" и т.д. можно было бы считать хорошими и плюсовать

Comment: @MBo ну я поставил там минус одним из первых, хоть как раз тот вопрос хотя бы по программированию, хоть и задавался множество раз тут и гуглиться за полсекунды

Comment: @dIm0n, как это он не связан с SO? Вопрос же про программирование :) Ну серьезно, "польза для SO" -- это польза для его участников и посетителей, а не просто слепое следование правилам.

Comment: @eanmos вопрос про обучение программированию, а не по программированию/администрированию; ruSO для вопросов по программированию/администрированию => вопрос не подходит для ruSO

Comment: @eanmos если хотите убрать эту тревогу и причину закрытия (изменить правила), то сделайте обсуждение на мете. Может быть, бОльшая часть сообщества будет согласна с вами

Comment: @dIm0n, меня вполне устраивают правила, вопрос действительно нужно закрыть, потому что единственно верного ответа не будет. Я к тому что, сам вопрос не плохой и полезен для некоторых участников.

Comment: @eanmos проблема в том, что когда вопрос минусуется, то ТС понимает, что он облажался и в следующий раз менее вероятно задаст такой вопрос. Более того, при определенном количестве заминусованным вопросов система сама заблокирует ему возможность дальнейшего задания вопросов. Плюсы же, наоборот, способствуют дальнейшему засорению ресурса такими вопросами, потому что некоторые участники и ТС могут подумать, что такие вопросы нормальные, и снова их задать